# Find the words in list of strings

Tags: r, regex, sapply, grepl

I have

```
words <- c("word1", "word")
text <- c("this is word1", "this is word2", "this is word4")
```

If I use `sapply(words, grepl, text)` gives you answer in TRUE and FALSE,
instead how can I get the exact words that has matched
such that the answer would be

```
"this is word1"
```

I being new to R pardon for such silly question.
Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: `sapply(words, grep, text, value = TRUE)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to create word boundary and then use `grep` to avoid any partial matching of strings and with `value = TRUE`, it returns the string instead of the index

```
grep(paste0("\\b(", paste(words, collapse="|"), ")\\b"), text, value = TRUE)
#[1] "this is word1"
```

Comment: Can it b checkd on word="test"
 text=c("test foo","word 1"," word2")
 grep(paste0("\\b(", paste(word, collapse="|"), ")\\b"), text, value = TRUE).which provides me "test foo", but not wanting that it should give me no answer or null(since no matcing found)?

Comment: @Domnick  Your condition is not clear to me.  If you want an exact match then use `==` or `%in%` i.e. `which(word==text)`

Comment: alright..just out of curiosity is it possible to do the vice-versa, meaning if the word matched, get the word that has been matched for from the variable *words*?